# Understanding PTR in context of Size Directives

Tags: assembly, x86

I am trying to understand how `PTR` works in the context of `Size Directive` and I am quite confused/unsure if my understanding is correct.

Let me take the 3 statements from [here](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) and try to explain what I think is happening here. The statements are as follows (x86, Intel Syntax):

```
mov BYTE PTR [ebx], 2
; Move 2 into the single byte at the address stored in EBX. 

mov WORD PTR [ebx], 2
; Move the 16-bit integer representation of 2 into the 2 bytes starting at the address in EBX. 

mov DWORD PTR [ebx], 2     
; Move the 32-bit integer representation of 2 into the 4 bytes starting at the address in EBX.
```

So for `mov BYTE PTR [ebx], 2`, this is what I believe is happening:

```
BYTE (8 Bits) → [2] (that is 2h, or am I wrong?)
```

consecutively:

```
WORD (16 Bits = BYTE + BYTE) → [0][2] (that is 0002h, or am I wrong?)
DWORD (32 Bits = WORD + WORD) → [0][0][0][2] (that is 0000,0002h, or am I wrong?)
```

I am choosing the end as

> starting at the address in EBX.

because that's what I believe is the little-endian format in x86.

Is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you split 8 bits into 4+4 and what do you mean by [0][2]? One byte is basic unit which is addressable in memory, so the first `mov` will write 0000_0010 bits into memory, at the `ebx` address. From machine point of view there's no reason to split that down to two 4 bits (nibbles). Any cell of memory contains 8 bits which allows for 256 different values. (and you got the little-endian wrong as well, but I'm curious about that `[0][2]` first, to understand you better).

Comment: @Ped7g Actually that was a mistake, I corrected it to what I intended to show.

Comment: Quite ok. And yes, you can write 32 bit "2" as 00000002h, if you want to "see" all 32 bits. After the assembler will turn your text source into machine code, there will be just 32 bits left of it (no formatting info), so they are all equal (2 = 2h = 00002h ...) in the source code, you should try to pick the one which is best readable for humans, for example working with bit masks is perfect fit for hexa or binary format, but initializing a loop counter with "1920 [pixels]" is probably better left in decimal. The final machine code is always binary, as that's the only thing available in PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, looks correct.

The fundamental unit is 1 byte, though.  4-bit hex digits are just a result of using that way of representing numbers in ASCII text.  The machine code for a byte-store ([`mov r/m8, imm8`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html)) is `opcode, modrm, imm8`, so the 0 in the high 4 bits is explicit in the machine code created by your assembler.

Same for the other sizes, actually, because there's no form of `mov` that sign-extends a byte.  The assembler has to encode the imm32 as `02 00 00 00` (because immediates in x86 machine code are little endian, same as data.)

You might find it informative to look at disassembly which includes a hexdump of the machine code.  One key thing to understand about asm is that it's just a text syntax for expressing machine-code.  What really matters is what the machine can do; once you know that you'll understand why certain limits exist.  For example, the scale factor in `[ebx + edi*8]` is encoded as a 0..3 shift count in a 2-bit field, which is why scale factors are limited to 1,2,4,8.

Different asm syntaxes exist for describing the same machine code.  In asm, you can leave out the `dword ptr` when it's implied by a register operand, but in machine code the operand size is always determined by the opcode + prefixes.

Comment: Yup, I made a mistake in the `fundamental is BYTE` part, corrected the question likewise.